# Pycharm can't find Django app 'users' when running tests

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm

I was handed a project which uses Django and Docker, but when I run Django tests Pycharm always seems to have problem finding the users application. Other people in the project have it running without problems but even though we tried to copy their settings, it wouldn't work. I also downgraded to their exact Pycharm version without success. What could be wrong?

I have Docker desktop running without any problem. It's able to create containers and all that. I've also included it in Pycharm with success.

[image]

I've also created an interpreter through Docker-compose with a valid .yml file. This file is my colleagues.

[image]

I've of course added it as my project interpreter.

[image]

I've set up a Django test configuration with appropriate interpreter and with an empty target field so that all applications in `INSTALLED_APPS` are run, [as per documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-django-test.html#1).

[image]

Still, the module 'users' cannot be found. Passing in `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.local` to the test configuration yields the same error.

[image]

However, when I run from the terminal, all works as expected.

[image]

What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the modern django setup (generated from [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)) which Pycharm seems to have trouble with. By right-clicking the folder and choosing *"Mark directory as"* and marking my project directory as "Sources Root" (i.e. the `project/project` folder), Pycharm was able to run it properly.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with a pytest + Docker run instead of Django. I cannot find anything about _why_ this matters to Pycharm.
Either the folder was not getting mounted into the docker container or it was not in the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

Did you try unchecking options related to PYTHONPATH in your run configuration?

[image]

It may override your modules path and cause such mess with finding them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the same problem remains